# sort icon is not working well

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use kendo grid sorting.

but, I think my grid`s sorting image is not cropped.

this occurs some pages not all. I don`t know what is different.

below is my case.

[image]

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I found why it occurs.

If span containing kendo icon img is applied css like width:100%, several icon shows.